# Trying to execute MySQL server from Java application

Tags: java, linux, terminal, runtime, processbuilder

I am trying to run MySQL server through Java application but I am not able to execute terminal commands through my application. Here is the code I am using.

```
String[] commands = new String[]{"cd /usr/local/mysql/support-files/", "echo "+password+" | sudo -S ./mysql.server start"};

Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(commands).start();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
String msg = "";
while(true) {
    msg = br.readLine();
    if(msg == null) break;
    System.out.println(msg);    
}
```

But this code is not executing those commands.

Comment: It looks like you're suffering from a possible case of the XY problem. Are you meaning to start a MySQL server just so your application can store some standlone data? In that case, SQLite would probably be a more reasonable approach.

Comment: No i just want my application to start the mysql server, i don't want to go to terminal and type command

Comment: Seems a little strange. Usually you'd start the MySQL server on server startup. What will run the java command?

Comment: I want to make it more handy to run mysql server. instead of typing command on terminal, i am trying to make a GUI an on click of button i want the command to get executed and run mysql server